# Uploading an image with application/octet-stream from an UTF-8 webpage with Perl

Tags: ajax, perl, file-upload, utf-8

I have a Javascript/Ajax fileuploader (https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader) which works fine on a latin-1 encoded webpage. Now I try to use it in an UTF-8 enviroment and it fails.
Here's my code (I simply need the image in a variable, saving is done somewhere else):

```
sub parseMultiPart{
  use CGI;
  use IO::Handle;
  use Encode;

  $CGITempFile::TMPDIRECTORY = $ENV{ADFRAME_TMP_FILES};
  $CGI::POST_MAX=1024 * 1024 * 5;
  #$CGI::PARAM_UTF8=1;
  my $cgi = new CGI;
  foreach $key ($cgi ->param) {
    my $upload = $cgi->upload($key);
    if(defined $upload) {

       # THIS DOES NOTHING SINCE UPLOAD IS NOT DEFINED

        my $file=$cgi->param($key);
        binmode $upload;
        my $data;
        while (read($upload_file, $upload, 1024)) {
            $main::in{$key} .=  $data;
        }

        $main::inct{$key} = $cgi->uploadInfo($file)->{'Content-Type'};
    }
    else {
        my @val = $cgi->param($key);

        # THIS DOES THE WORK
        if (scalar @val == 1) {
            $main::in{$key} = $val[0];
        }
        # /

        else {
            $main::in{$key} = \@val;  # save value as an array ref
        }
    }


}
}
1;
```

Then in the next step:

```
if (open (HI, ">$storePath/$filename")) {
        binmode HI;
        print HI $data;
        close(HI);
}
```

There are several issues here:

- `CGI->upload()` doesn't recognize this as upload. I only noticed now since it never caused any problems.
- Using `multipart/formdata` causes the server to abort and not send anything.
- Using it like this I get a `Wide character in print` message.
- If I `encode $val[0]` I won't get the message, the resulting file is still corrupted.
- If I `binmode $val[0]` I get `wide characters in print`

Can anyone help out??

Thanks,
thomas

EDIT: Here's "Follow TCP Stream":

---

```
 POST /cgi-bin/adframe/upload/image_upload.html?ITEM_ID=1&CATEGORY=1_1&qqfile=button_logout.gif HTTP/1.1
 Host: productspecial
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 583
 Origin: http://productspecial
 X-Mime-Type: image/gif
 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
 X-File-Name: button_logout.gif
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
 Content-Type: application/octet-stream
 Accept: */*
 Referer: http://productspecial/cgi-bin/adframe/online_produktdatenbank/1_komplettbikes/1_1_fullsuspension/1_1_fullsuspension.html?ITEM_ID=1&id=134149338812700131663
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
 Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

 GIF89aD......................................................................................................!.......,....D........ud...Y.*y....qJ....8.....6..[..rh,....ez..lI.q.D....&........n.....B.....>..L..u.............$...........}..............................}..}........................}....}...}.........}...................}...4h.............A...H.(P.....q..qB....<.8.CI..I..4y..H..^Z..kB...=t.S...>......(J.D{*U*R.@z..R...@0.
.>.. k@
...@.....g..m%....p.V.K.n].t..........I.,A0a....^l......
n...a..+..........V....p.T.FMa5j..N..M.....s......
.y.........+_..A....K.N.....;HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 05 Jul 2012 13:32:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 104
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

.............MNN-..*)*M.I..I.R.O.-...MLO-./J,.wqus....+.KW.)-..R..utw.7.C..4SKsSK...4u...*..5...~.
.Y...
```

Comment: It is useful to see the HTTP traffic, please capture the upload of a tiny image and show the full POST request: use the browser's network panel (ctrl+shift+i) from Firefox Firebug, Opera Dragonfly, Chromium Web Inspector. Alternatively, use Wireshark, complete a capture,filter the expression `http` in the combo-box near the top, select the packet that starts the upload, menu Analyze → Follow TCP stream and copy/paste the text representation.

Comment: @daxim - just posted the output of Wireshark

Answer (score 2):

You Content-Type is not one for use with CGI->upload, from the CGI documentation

> If POSTed data is not of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded or
> multipart/form-data, then the POSTed data will not be processed, but
> instead be returned as-is in a parameter named POSTDATA.  To retrieve
> it, use code like this:
>
> ```
>    my $data = $query->param('POSTDATA');
> ```

**update:** Here is  a patch against CGI.pm-3.59 to avoid PUTDATA/POSTDATA getting corrupted

It also provides PUTDATA/POSTDATA convenience methods to use instead of param

```
diff -ruN CGI.pm-3.59-orig/lib/CGI.pm CGI.pm-3.59/lib/CGI.pm
--- CGI.pm-3.59-orig/lib/CGI.pm 2011-12-30 05:31:41.000000000 -0800
+++ CGI.pm-3.59/lib/CGI.pm  2012-07-25 05:08:19.656250000 -0700
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@

 # The revision is no longer being updated since moving to git. 
 $CGI::revision = '$Id: CGI.pm,v 1.266 2009/07/30 16:32:34 lstein Exp $';
-$CGI::VERSION='3.59';
+$CGI::VERSION='3.5901';

 # HARD-CODED LOCATION FOR FILE UPLOAD TEMPORARY FILES.
 # UNCOMMENT THIS ONLY IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING.
@@ -457,8 +457,12 @@
     my @result = @{$self->{param}{$name}};

     if ($PARAM_UTF8) {
-      eval "require Encode; 1;" unless Encode->can('decode'); # bring in these functions
-      @result = map {ref $_ ? $_ : $self->_decode_utf8($_) } @result;
+      if( $name eq 'PUTDATA' or $name eq 'POSTDATA' ){
+        warn "skip decoding utf8 for special param $name\n" if DEBUG;
+      } else {
+        eval "require Encode; 1;" unless Encode->can('decode'); # bring in these functions
+        @result = map {ref $_ ? $_ : $self->_decode_utf8($_) } @result;
+      }
     }

     return wantarray ?  @result : $result[0];
@@ -692,7 +696,7 @@
         && defined($ENV{'CONTENT_TYPE'})
         && $ENV{'CONTENT_TYPE'} !~ m|^application/x-www-form-urlencoded|
    && $ENV{'CONTENT_TYPE'} !~ m|^multipart/form-data| ) {
-       my($param) = $meth . 'DATA' ;
+       my($param) = $meth . 'DATA' ; # POSTDATA/PUTDATA
        $self->add_parameter($param) ;
        push (@{$self->{param}{$param}},$query_string);
        undef $query_string ;
@@ -985,6 +989,14 @@

 %SUBS = (

+'PUTDATA'=> <<'END_OF_FUNC',
+sub PUTDATA   { local $CGI::PARAM_UTF8=0; shift()->param('PUTDATA', @_)  }
+END_OF_FUNC
+
+'POSTDATA'=> <<'END_OF_FUNC',
+sub POSTDATA  { local $CGI::PARAM_UTF8=0; shift()->param('POSTDATA', @_) }
+END_OF_FUNC
+
 'URL_ENCODED'=> <<'END_OF_FUNC',
 sub URL_ENCODED { 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; }
 END_OF_FUNC
```

Comment: Thanks @obmib. My problem is, that this data is corrupted when coming from a UTF-8 encoded page.

Comment: If you avoid $CGI::PARAM_UTF8=1;  if you use  $CGI::PARAM_UTF8=0; then the data won't get corrupted , though CGI.pm really ought to refuse to corrupt POSTDATA

Comment: You can [follow the status of the related CGI.pm patch](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=79102)